# How to splice an image URL field returned by the server and load the img correctly in the vue?

Tags: javascript, web, vue.js

This is an example,This is the data returned by the server:

```
[
{
        "Id":8,
        "Title":"123123",
        "Creatorid":1,
        "ImgUrl":"\upload\images\item\banner\1.jpeg",
        "Content":null
    },
    {
        "Id":9,
        "Title":"123",
        "Creatorid":1,
        "ImgUrl":"\upload\images\item\banner\2.jpeg",
        "Content":null
    },
    {
        "Id":10,
        "Title":"",
        "Creatorid":1,
        "ImgUrl":"\upload\images\item\banner\3.jpeg",
        "Content":null
    }
]
```

this html:

```
<el-table :data="homeTableData" style="width: 100%">
            <el-table-column label=“image” width="300">
              <template slot-scope="scope">
                <span>{{scope.row.ImgUrl}}</span>
                <img :src="getImage(scope.row.ImgUrl)" alt=“loding” style="width:50px; height:50px;">
              </template>
            </el-table-column>
</el-table>
```

this js:

```
  methods: {

    getImage(src) {
      console.log(src);
      let temp = "test:8080/website/" + src;
      this.$axios
        .get(temp)
        .then(res => {
          console.log("ccc",res)
          return res;
        })
        .catch(error => {});
    }
}
```

**Now the problem is that img doesn't show images**

The reason is that axios doesn't return anything. What should I do? Using synchronization?

but the content of the return is the Request URL:

`http://localhost:8080/website/upload/images/item/banner/ [object % 20 promise]`

How do you gracefully load images in a vue?

Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

You are not returning anything from the function. Return the `this.$axios` request. Also, this request is asynchronous, so it would be best to wait for the function to return the data:

```
methods: {
    async getImage(src) {
      console.log(src);
      let temp = "test:8080/website/" + src;
      return await this.$axios
        .get(temp)
        .then(res => {
          console.log("ccc",res)
          return res;
        })
        .catch(error => {});
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but the content of the return is the Request URL: ```http://localhost:8080/website/upload/images/item/banner/ [object % 20 promise]```

Comment: @BaiClassmateXiao please can you tell me the value of res?

Comment: It returns an image . But now we can't request image because of banner/ [object % 20 promise]